# Angular List Selection with Dual List Box Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, listbox

I am using the angular dual list box library at :http://frapontillo.github.io/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox/

I am trying to get the selected item in the first list box to not avail. No events are exposed that I can tie into and I am not sure what the easiest way to get the selection would be. If I was using the jquery one I could get the "option:selected" property. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/4zt4k5er/

Comment: Thanks. This is a good example, but I really like the dual list box library. And unfortunately it is sometimes really hard to know how or what to modify to get it to work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem, got around it using the Form submit, that then populates the results on the right hand side, and updates the model...so try :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="update()">
   //....your markup here
</from>
```

Add to your controller : 
    $scope.update = function () {
     //your update code
    }